# Iterating through a list with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, iteration

I have a query which I'd like to run, but for multiple id's in a list. Below is the example code:

```
    `SELECT avg(t1.Percentage) 
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        checkins.id_user as userID,
        count(checkins.id_check_in) as Aantal,
(SELECT COUNT(events.id_event)
            FROM
            events
            WHERE events.id_event_group = 146
            AND `start` > '2014-01-01 00:00:00') as AantalEvents,
count(checkins.id_check_in) / (SELECT COUNT(events.id_event)
            FROM
            events
            WHERE events.id_event_group = 146
            AND `start` > '2014-01-01 00:00:00') as Percentage
    FROM
checkins
    LEFT JOIN events ON
events.id_event = checkins.id_event
    WHERE checkins.id_user IN(
        SELECT  checkins.id_user as userID
        FROM checkins
        WHERE id_event = **26276**) # < This is the ID that I want to change through a list)
            AND events.id_event_group = 146
            GROUP BY checkins.id_user)t1 ;`
```

I highlighted the ID that I want to change based on a list that I define with a different query (list of id's). Is this even possible with SQL? I'm using DBeaver as tool.

Comment: What's the database? It can be either SQL Server or MySQL, not both.

Comment: Sorry, it's MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

SQL works on the principle of 'sets'.  That means that when you execute functions in your `select` statement, it is done on all rows that are returned by that statement.

This means that if you simply specify a list of values to filter your query by, either with an `in` statement or a derived table, you will return the corresponding values for each and every row from that list.

If you have a static list of `id_event` values you can do:

```
where id_event in(1,2,3,4,etc)
```

and if they are in a table that you want to apply a set of filters to to get your list of events, you can just add an `inner join` to your query:

```
select Columns
from OtherTables
    inner join checkins
        on <join condition 1>
          and <join condition 2>
          and <checkin filter 1>
          and <checkin filter 2>
```

## Edit to add after clarification

SQL aggregates work on groupings of data.  Something like the following will aggregate the entire dataset that is returned as no grouping is applied:

```
select sum(Col) as Total
from Table
```

Whereas something like this will give you a total for each `ID` value:

```
select ID
      ,sum(Col) as Total
from Table
group by ID
```

Comment: I understand this, perhaps I framed my question incorrectly. The end result, or calculation, is needed per id_event individually. If I use IN, it will add all events together. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can add your `id_event` to your `select` list and `group by` to get aggregated results by each `id_event` value.  I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I've already used a grouping function above. Basically, I want to calculate things over a set of users. That set of users is based on to what event they went to. I want to do the calculations over a different set of users every time. So what you are suggesting will not work unfortunately.

Comment: @StefanMusch  The grouping would go on your outermost `select`, for which you have no grouping specified yet.  If you find this still doesn't work for you, rewrite the query using the principles I have outlined above so you can have the multiple levels of groupings you require.

Comment: Thanks for your help, although I still can't get it to work. Are you sure there is no way to do it in the way I asked? I've read something about a CURSOR to iterate through a list, but I don't quite understand that process

Comment: @StefanMusch  You almost certainly do not need a cursor, they are very bad things to use in SQL.  If you still can't get the query to work, please post your table schema, some test data and your desired output into your question and we can go from there.